# Installing a service on Windows Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am managing the installation of our product to be installed on our clients servers.  The installation includes an application that is a service and I am installing that service with the command line through the installer.

The question is, when I install a new version of the application, the uninstall process I believe shuts down the service so it can remove the EXE for it.  Do I have to UNINSTALL and REINSTALL the service, or do I need to just install the new application and just start the service as the new EXE for the service will be replaced?

Comment: If the path of the service doesn't change (including file name), then you're good to go.

Comment: I believe updating the exe and restarting the service should be enough.
This is how I usually pushed updates to my windows service and pending some unusual case, I never had to reinstall the service itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to UNINSTALL it, but you do need to STOP it if it is running, so that the lock on the EXE is released. Once EXE is updated - you can START the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to update any needed files as long as the service is not running.